# Can't deploy site on tomcat on mac

Tags: macos, tomcat

I cannot figure out how to deploy a website (not app) on Tomcat on my mac.  I just want to have Tomcat serve the file index.html.  I tried creating the file myapp.xml in library/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost with the content:

```
    <Content path="/myapp" docBase="/Users/jerryk/Development/myapp" />
```

But when I attempt to access the site with

```
    "http://localhost:8080/myapp" or "localhost:8080/myapp/index.html"
```

I get a resource not found error.

```
    http://localhost:8080 brings up the Tomcat control panel.
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?  FWIW, this works fine on windows.

Thanks,

Jerry

Comment: If http://localhost:8080 brings up the Tomcat control panel that isn't a default Tomcat installation. There are lots of configuration settings that a packager can tweak that could cause the behavior you are seeing. You need to figure out where CATALINA_BASE is, then which server.xml file is being used and then look at the Host element(s) and check the various deployment settings.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what's going on with Windows, but theoretically, the docBase must point either to a .war file, or a directory that has the same layout as a war file.

So, you can't just have an index.html in that directory, you also need at least a WEB-INF directory with a minimal web.xml in it.

See, for example,  http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat.html

Comment: web.xml (and by extension the WEB-INF directory) has been optional since at least Servlet 2.5.